# No boot device after install on HP ProBook 4540s

Tags: system-installation, boot

I just finished installing Freya on my HP ProBook 4540s laptop. After successful install, it prompted to remove the install USB and restart. So I did. After restarting, I get a `No bootable image found, notebook will shutdown` message.

It's worth noting that my **Boot Mode** is set to **UEFI Native (Without CSM)**. Also, the HDD I'm trying to install it to is a brand new Toshiba 500GB HDD and I don't intend to dual boot.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled using the **Legacy** boot mode in BIOS and now it's working fine. Apparently, HP ProBook 4540s' UEFI feature is buggy or my BIOS version needs updating.

Comment: I could install on my HP Pavilion g7 in UEFI mode